# Position auto-scaled UI element with Camera.WorldToScreenPoint

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a `Canvas`.
I'm creating some `Text` elements right above 3D objects in the scene with this code:

```
Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.dices[x, z].transform.position);
screenPos.x -= 25;
screenPos.y += 10;
newScoreItem.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = screenPos;
```

On Android my UI elements are tiny so I set the surrounding Canvas` UI Scale Mode to "Scale with screen size".

The problem is that the position I determine with the code above doesn't match the one of scaled canvas. My `Text` elements are scaled but at the completely wrong location.

How may I solve that problem?

Correct positioning (on Mac):

[image]

Wrong positioning (somewhere out of the screne) with `Scale with screen size`(on Android):

[image]

Comment: A screenshot of what "right position" and "wrong position" are would really help.

Comment: I added two screenshots but I doubt it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First check Anchors Min/Max of the Text "newScoreItem": point 0,0 on the screen is in the bottom left corner, so Anchors Min/Max should be 0 (bottom left).

Second - it matters how did you set Screen Match Mode.
If it is set to match width or height you can use the following script:

```
    float refWidth = 800f; // reference resolution - width - set in Canvas Scaler 
    float refHeight = 480f; // reference resolution - height - set in Canvas Scaler
    bool matchWidth = true; //true if screen match mode is set to match the width, 
                    //false if is set to match the height
    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(this.dices[x,y].transform.position);
    if (matchWidth) {
        screenPos.x *= refWidth / Screen.width;
        screenPos.y *= refWidth / Screen.width;
    } else {
        screenPos.x *= refHeight / Screen.height;
        screenPos.y *= refHeight / Screen.height;
    }
    screenPos.x -= 25f;
    screenPos.y += 10f;
    newScoreItem.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = screenPos;
```

It works for me, although maybe there is easier way to do it.